# cohomology of permutation group with mod 2 coefficient

Tags: algebraic-topology, permutations, homology-cohomology, symmetric-groups, group-cohomology

Let $S_n$ be the permutation group of order $n$. Let $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. What is 
the cohomology algebra
$$H^*(S_n;\mathbb{Z}_2)?$$

For $n=2$, $BS_2=\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ hence I know the answer.

The papers are very difficult. For example, what is 
$$
H^*(BS_3;\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the places where generalizing makes structure more visible.  If you are willing to consider $S_n$ for all $n$ at once, i.e., study
$$
\coprod_n BS_n,
$$ 
then the cohomology algebra has *two* products making it a **Hopf ring** (a ring object in the category of coalgebras).

[Giusti, Salvatore, and Sinha](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.3292v3.pdf) studied this and include explicit rules for multiplication in terms of combinatorial objects called skyline diagrams (reminiscent of Young diagrams, not surprisingly).

[image: Skyline diagram for multiplication in $BS_8$]

---

EDIT:

Have a look at this more recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4137) by Giusti and Sinha that is more easily digestible and goes into considerably more detail.  Also, there's the book [*Cohomology of Finite Groups*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sKmshEctdw0C) by Adem and Milgram.

Comment: Dear Prof. Sammy Black, the paper is very difficult. Could you give me an example? For example, what is $H^*(BS_3;\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Comment: Well, $H^*(BS_{2k+1}; \Bbb{Z}_2) \cong H^*(BS_{2k}; \Bbb{Z}_2)$, so $H^*(BS_3; \Bbb{Z}_2)$ is again the polynomial ring in one generator.